# Accessing scope from within element.bind, within link function of directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am experiencing some problems within the link function of my directive. I am starting a new timeout within mousedown event bound to the element, then clearing it on the mouseup. The timeout is not clearing and also other variables I call on the scope are not updating within the element.bind functions. When I log to console, both functions are being triggered but the $scope doesn't seem to update until after the timeout has completed?

How can I make this work? JS fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/xrh6dhf9/

HTML

```
<div ng-app="dr" ng-controller="testCtrl">
<holddelete param="myDeletedMessage" update-fn="doCallback(msg)"></test>
```

JavaScript

```
var app = angular.module('dr', []);
app.controller("testCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.myDeletedMessage = "Deleted Succesfully";
    $scope.doCallback = function(msg) {        
        alert(msg);
    }
});
app.directive('holddelete', ['$timeout', function( $timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            param: '=',
            updateFn: '&'
        },
        template: "<a href> <i class='fa fa-times fa-fw'></i>Delete  {{message}}</a>",
        replace: true,        
        link: function($scope, element, attrs) {  

            $scope.mytimeout = null;

           $scope.message = ">";

            element.bind('mousedown', function (e) {
                console.log("mousedown");
                $scope.message = "- Hold 2 Secs";
                $scope.mytimeout = $timeout(function(){ 
                    $scope.updateFn({msg: $scope.param});
                }, 2000)
            });
            element.bind('mouseup', function (e) {
                console.log("mouseup");
                $scope.mytimeout = null;

                $scope.message = ">";
            })
        }
    }
}]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of setting timeout as null use

```
$timeout.cancel($scope.mytimeout);
```

Also instead of setting event handlers using element.bind pass execute methods in scope with `ng-mousedown` and `ng-mouseup`

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xrh6dhf9/1/

Comment: I have added a nice countdown to the hold to delete function here: http://jsfiddle.net/v98vuz3h/